# Assigning multi row values to a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to assign values of multiple rows to a variable in **VBA**   **example:**

```
Dim campaign_date As Variant
campaign_date = "ABC vs. XYZ Report
n Weeks Comparison
ABC - January 30, 2011 - February 26, 2011 
XYZ - October 31, 2010 - November 27, 2010"
```

The above code is not working.  Please suggest a good way for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim campaign_date As Variant
campaign_date = "ABC vs. XYZ Report " & vbCrLf  & _
"n Weeks Comparison" & vbCrLf  & _
"ABC - January 30, 2011 - February 26, 2011 " & vbCrLf & _
"XYZ - October 31, 2010 - November 27, 2010"
```

The underscore `_` is the line-continuation character, the ampersand `&` concatenates strings  and the keyword `vbCrLf` is a linebreak (Cr = Carriage Return, Lf = Line Feed).